# Spring REST calls response type objects with tiny differences

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've a service that needs to return two similar responses. The first response is `days` which is an array of String called `availableDays` and the other response is `times` which is an array of String called `availableTimes`.

I've done the first one (`days`) and my response object looks like this:

```
public class AvailableDaysTimesResponse {
  private String status;
  private String[] avaialbleDays;
  ...
}
```

The question is:
Do I need to create a different response class and have a `String[]` variable in it called `availableTimes` in order to return the `availableTimes` or can I somehow use this class to change the name of the array variable in the *JSON* sent back to the caller?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same class using the *Jackson* `@JsonView` annotation.

> @JsonView is used to indicate the View in which the field will be
>   included while serialization/deserialization and is very helpful when
>   it is needed to include different fields of object while serialization
>   for different use cases. @JsonView annotation is supported on Spring
>   for v≥4.1

First you must create a class for declaring your views.

```
public class AvailableDaysTimesViews {

    public static class AvailableDaysResponse {
    }

    public static class AvailableTimesResponse {
    }
}
```

Then you must include these changes in `AvailableDaysTimesResponse` class

```
public class AvailableDaysTimesResponse {

    @JsonView({
        AvailableDaysTimesViews.AvailableDaysResponse.class,
        AvailableDaysTimesViews.AvailableTimesResponse.class
    })
    private String status;

    @JsonView(AvailableDaysTimesViews.AvailableDaysResponse.class)
    private String[] avaialbleDays;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("availableTimes")
    @JsonView(AvailableDaysTimesViews.AvailableTimesResponse.class)
    public String[] getAvailableTimes() {
        return avaialbleDays;
    }

    public String[] getAvaialbleDays() {
        return avaialbleDays;
    }

    public void setAvaialbleDays(String[] avaialbleDays) {
        this.avaialbleDays = avaialbleDays;
    }   
}
```

How to use your *JSON* views with *Spring*

```
@JsonView(AvailableDaysTimesViews.AvailableDaysResponse.class)
@RequestMapping("/days")
public @ResponseBody
AvailableDaysTimesResponse getDays() {
    AvailableDaysTimesResponse resp = new AvailableDaysTimesResponse();
    resp.setStatus("DONE");
    resp.setAvaialbleDays(new String[]{"MONDAY"});
    return resp;
}

@JsonView(AvailableDaysTimesViews.AvailableTimesResponse.class)
@RequestMapping("/times")
public @ResponseBody
AvailableDaysTimesResponse getTimes() {
    AvailableDaysTimesResponse resp = new AvailableDaysTimesResponse();
    resp.setStatus("DONE");
    resp.setAvaialbleDays(new String[]{"ONCE", "TWICE"});
    return resp;
}
```

References:

[Jackson @JsonView for serializing and deserializing object](https://medium.com/@_neha_kumari/jackson-jsonview-for-serialising-and-deserialising-object-a54005c875c0)

[Jackson JSON Views with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to create a separate response class. You can add another variable in the same class and Spring rest depending upon the values received from api will automatically map them on the response class, all you have to do is fetch your respective array as per your use. All you need to do is make sure that the variable names in class used to generate service response is sane as variable names in class to which the response is converted into.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

**Option 1**

Continue with a single field as you already have defined. Define two get methods and add a boolean flag to indicate which field is set. Depending on this boolean flag return the value from each of these get methods:

```
private static class Person {
    private String name;
    private boolean isKey1;

    public Person(String name, boolean isKey1) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isKey1 = isKey1;
    }

    public String getKey1() {
        return isKey1 ? name : null;
    }

    public String getKey2() {
        return isKey1 ? null : name;
    }
}

Person p1 = new Person("abc", true);
Person p2 = new Person("xyz", false);
```

This option is not preferred is you have more than one field to control conditionally.

**Option 2**

Define two fields and two getter methods. Set one of the values from the corresponding API.

```
private static class Person1{
    private String key1;
    private String key2;

    public Person1(String key1, String key2){
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    public String getKey1(){
        return this.key1;
    }

    public String getKey2(){
        return this.key2;
    }
}

Person1 p1 = new Person1("abc", null);
Person1 p2 = new Person1(null, "xyz");
```

**Option 3**

Define two different DTO classes. Clear and simple.

**Notes:**

In Option 1 and Option 2, since one of the values will be null do one of the following:

Add the following in application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

Add the following annotation to the DTO class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a simple `Map<String, Object>` as a return value if you do not want to create many classes for all the different use cases. That is not what I would normally recommend, but it is a quick way (for prototyping) that is often overlooked.